# Bug in Local variable Table construction when Using Javap -v?

Tags: java, javap

I tried the following code :

```
class testingFinally {
  public static String getMessage() {
    String s = "hi";
    try {
        return s;
    } finally {
        s = null;
    }
  }

 public static void main(String a[]) {
    System.out.println(getMessage());
 }
}
```

The output is *obviously* `"hi"`. But when I looked at the byte code using `javap -v`, I get the following.

```
public static java.lang.String getMessage();
descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=1, locals=3, args_size=0
     0: ldc           #16                 // String hi
     2: astore_0
     3: aload_0
     4: astore_2
     5: aconst_null
     6: astore_0
     7: aload_2
     8: areturn
     9: astore_1
    10: aconst_null
    11: astore_0
    12: aload_1
    13: athrow

  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      10     0     s   Ljava/lang/String;
```

There is only one **Local variable** shown in the Table  where as 3 local variables (0,1,2 check byte code `load` and `store` instructions) are being used. Is there an explanation for this?. Are *local variables* with value null (eventual value) being ignored?

Comment: What flags did you use for `javac`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I compiled the code in eclipse. No *specific* flags.

Comment: Well, there are flags or not. Literally `javac TheClass.java` or what?

Comment: I get the name number of locals with `javac -g:none TheClass.java`, FWIW. Interesting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -   I used plain `javac MyClass.java`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Interestingly, JDK6 says I have only 1 local variable, jdk8 says I have 3 (but doesn't print the local variables table) :P

Comment: Yeah, I was using Java 8.